# How To Exclude Rows From Other Partitions In moving Average Window Function - #SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I am using a window function for a 3 day moving average. I want to partition this function to get the moving average of two different products.

The first row of the product B's moving average is using values of Product A's since product A sits above it in the table.

How can I avoid this and only use the rows WITHIN the current partition? I've looked quite a bit for a solution to this and cannot find anything.

Current Code:

```
select date, product, units_sold,
  avg(units_sold) OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY date
     ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as moving_average 
from sales_table;
```

This is the current result:

| date | product | units_sold | moving_average |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | product A | 10 | 10.0 |  |
| 1/2/2020 | product A | 20 | 15.0 |  |
| 1/3/2020 | product A | 30 | 20.0 |  |
| 1/4/2020 | product A | 30 | 26.7 |  |
| 1/5/2020 | product A | 25 | 28.3 |  |
| 1/1/2020 | product B | 12 | 22.3 | INCORRECT |
| 1/2/2020 | product B | 8 | 15.0 | INCORRECT |
| 1/3/2020 | product B | 10 | 10.0 |  |
| 1/4/2020 | product B | 6 | 8.0 |  |
| 1/5/2020 | product B | 4 | 6.7 |  |

This is what I'm looking for:

| date | product | units_sold | moving_average |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | product A | 10 | 10.0 |  |
| 1/2/2020 | product A | 20 | 15.0 |  |
| 1/3/2020 | product A | 30 | 20.0 |  |
| 1/4/2020 | product A | 30 | 26.7 |  |
| 1/5/2020 | product A | 25 | 28.3 |  |
| 1/1/2020 | product B | 12 | 12.0 | CORRECT |
| 1/2/2020 | product B | 8 | 10.0 | CORRECT |
| 1/3/2020 | product B | 10 | 10.0 |  |
| 1/4/2020 | product B | 6 | 8.0 |  |
| 1/5/2020 | product B | 4 | 6.7 |  |

Comment: Your current SQL has a syntax issue. `PARTITION BY` should have comma separated columns.  What is `BUY`?

Comment: Your code is correct.  I think you are misinterpreting the results.

Comment: I am not misinterpreting the results. Row for 1/1/2020 for product B should not be using the sales from product A in it's moving average calculation.

Comment: Your code works fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc2914647ad3c88ddc761c31fb1d9e45

Comment: The code works fine, but the result is not what I want. I am looking for the 1/1 and 1/2 product B rows to NOT use the preceding product A rows in their moving average calculation.

Comment: The results are exactly what you expect. Did you check the link in my previous comment?

Comment: I apologize, you are correct! For some reason this is not working in my Snowflake environment... I assumed it would be the same but I guess not!